# How many window types spark structured streaming supports for now or will support in the future?

Tags: apache-spark, window, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

Currently when I reading documents of flink I found there are lots of [window semantics](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.1/apis/streaming/windows.html#windows) supports in flink like the tumbling window, sliding window, session window and custom window implementing

Could any one can tell me how many window semantics built-in or defined in spark structured streaming or spark streaming for now or in the future? 
And is it possible to implement an application upon [session window](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.1/apis/streaming/windows.html#session-windows) in spark structured streaming ?

Thanks for any ideas or suggestion  ~

Answer (score 0):

Here is the spark session window associated [jira-10816](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10816), session window in spark will be supported in the future release version.